# CTRL+F (find dialog) not appearing in tables/queries in Microsoft Access 2010. But CTRL+H works just fine

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016, microsoft-access-2010

If I pull up a table like this:

[image]

And try to press CTRL+F, the find dialog does not appear.

But if I press CTRL+H, the find/replace dialog *does* appear:

[image]

I can then of course go to the find tab. But any ideas on why CTRL+F is not working? This is installed on Windows Server 2016 (Windows 10).

EDIT:

After further researching, I found that CTRL+F doesn't work in any Office 10 products, across 7 different servers.

Comment: Do you have any software installed that might be taking over shortcut commands? Is it just you with the issue? Is it on one computer or multiple?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Nothing that I could find. Office 2010 is installed on 7 servers and it's happening on all 7 servers. Office 2016 is also installed, but it's not affecting 2016.

Comment: When doing CTRL-F, does the search box appear along the left side of the screen?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch In Access 2010, the navigation pane is there by default. But CTRL+F should make the find window appear. In Word 2010, the navigation pane does not appear, when you would expect it to. But I can toggle it manually: https://i.imgur.com/yhDfAGA.png

Answer (score 0):

I never actually noticed this until you mentioned it. In 2010 (and O365 that I have), the behavior of `CTRL-F` was changed so instead of popping up a box, it placed the search in the navigation pane on the left.

To get the `CTRL-F` to work again, follow the directions here: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T011389_Making_Ctrl_F_Work_Traditionally.html

Comment: CTRL+F *was* missing from Word 2010 for EditFind. But adding it did nothing. And Access 2010 (which is the app I'm most focused on), doesn't have the ability to customize keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: So when you added it to 'Press new shortcut key:', you saw CTRL-F and then clicked Assign? After assigning and closing it, did you go back in and verify that it's in the 'Current keys:' box?

Comment: Correct. I assigned it, closed Word, opened it, and it didn't take effect. I checked the shortcut and it's still there. I then logged out of the server, logged back in, verified the shortcut, but the issue was still there.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Word’s Ctrl + F problem](https://office-watch.com/2014/words-ctrl-f-problem/)
discusses this same problem:

> Ctrl + F used to open the Find dialog but now opens the Navigation Pane instead. There’s no shortcut to open the now-named Advanced Find dialog box with all the useful extra features.
>
> You’d think a solution would be to re-assign Ctrl + F to go to the Advanced Find dialog.  After all any shortcut can be changed from Options | Customize Ribbon | Keyboard Shortcuts.
>
> But maybe not … the VBA command for the Advanced Find dialog is FindDialog (according to Microsoft itself) but that command isn’t on the Customize Keyboard list.

The only solution this article suggests is :

> the workaround, press Ctrl + H which opens the neighboring Replace dialog.  Then press Alt + D to switch to the Find dialog.
>
> It’s not as simple or fast as Ctrl + F but that’s all Microsoft leaves us with.

If the solution of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
is too cumbersome, it is possible to use
[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to remap in the context of the Access process
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to this key-combination by using the following script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe msaccess.exe
^f::
send ^h
send !d
return
#IfWinActive
```

Unfortunately I cannot test this script.

Comment: That would only explain the Word issue though. It doesn't explain why Access is breaking when there is no navigation pane. The version of Office 2010 I have installed is the exact same version on an old 2008 server where it works. It's a weird situation.

Comment: Office has some common code for all its products, so problems in one may also arrive in others. In addition, an Office installation that is upgraded from a previous version will not be identical to a fresh install. This might be what you are seeing.

Comment: I understand what you mean, it's just an odd situation. It's hard to believe that there's no solution for it. And this wasn't an upgrade. It's a fresh install.

Comment: There's no solution as this is by design.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The find dialog works perfectly on MS Access 2010 on a different server, with the exact same version. Installing on a new server should work, unless something is broken. It can't be by design, as it works elsewhere.

Comment: Is the server where it works also a fresh install? And what does Ctrl-F do on that server?

Comment: As far as I know it is, but I can't be sure.

Comment: What does Ctrl-F do on that server? If it calls up a dialog, then I don't think that this is a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've employed across a couple of my personal and work pc's is the following:

1. Right click on the Ribbon (HOME or any other option)
2. Click on CUSTOMIZE THE RIBBON
3. Click on CUSTOMIZE KEYBOARD in the bottom left corner beside "Keyboard shortcuts
4. In the "Press new shortcut key" box, press and hold "CTRL + F"
   ** You should see "Currently assigned to: NAvSearchPane" or whatever shortcut is assigned to CTRL+F appear just below the "Current keys:" box
5. Scroll down the "Categories" list and select ALL COMMANDS
6. Scroll down the "Commands:" list and select EDITFIND
7. Click on the ASSIGN button in the bottom lefthand corner
8. Click CLOSE on :Customize Keyboard" window
9. Click OK in the "Word Options" window

You're all set! Hit CTRL+F on your keyboard and the dialogue box should now appear. I didn't know how to post this to the Microsoft forums sadly, but hey, hope you find the answer to your Find/Replace dialogue box no longer popping up issue!